# event.which is undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to restrict my key input in the text field to numbers or backspace or space so I am checking before I set state and preventing default behavior of event in other cases but I am not able to locate `event.which` property of event or `keyCode` for that matter.
I tried `event.persist()` to see but still the same there is no property by the name of `which` in `event`.
There is a `which` in `nativeEvent` of `event` but it is always 0.

Here is the component that is there in my app.js I am using textfield of material-ui instead of normal input.

`MobileNumber.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';


export interface MobileNumberProps {

}

export interface MobileNumberState {
    value: any
}

class MobileNumber extends React.Component<MobileNumberProps, MobileNumberState> {
    state = {
        value: 0,
    }
    handleChange = (value: any) => {
        this.setState({ value: value })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <TextField
                type="number"
                onChange={(event: any) => {
                    event.persist();
                    console.log('event is ', event);
                    if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 0 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                        console.log('stopped')
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('event which is ', event.which);
                        console.log('allowed');
                        let value = event.target.value
                        this.handleChange(value);
                    }
                }}
                value={this.state.value}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default MobileNumber;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible issues:

1. [`which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) and [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) are both deprecated, so it's not entirely surprising that React's synthetic events don't have them. The modern property is [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

   For example, this:

   ```js
   if (event.which != 8 && event.which != 0 && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
   ```

   could be written like this:

   ```js
   if (event.key !== "Backspace" && event.key !== "" && (event.key < "0" || event.key > "C")) {
   ```
2. Note that the `change` event is a plain [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), not [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent). It doesn't have key-specific information because it's not a key-specific event. Use a key event instead if you need to know what key was pressed ([`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) is probably what you want in this case).

---

Side note: There's no reason to call `persist` in your example, you don't try to use the properties after the event handler returns. In general, avoid `persist`. If you **did** need `key` after the handler returned, you'd grab it to a local variable instead:

```
const { key } = event;
// ...use `key`...
```

Comment: @ash1102 - `change` isn't a keyboard event, I've updated the answer to address that.

Comment: thanks T.j. onChange was the real problem it is working fine with onkeydown but i'll be sure to use key instead of which